# Recent Microsoft patch breaks UWP printing to serial printers

Tags: printing, uwp, serial-port, windows-update

Recently Microsoft deployed some security patch that has broken UWP printing to serial printers.  These are printers that interface to Windows through either a USB serial port or a Bluetooth serial port.  Symptoms -

Upon printing, a print notification appears:

Print Notification
Error printing on [printer name]
The printer couldn't print [print job name]

The print job appears in the printer queue with "Error - Printing" as status.  Restarting the print job from the queue causes the page to successfully print, however having to restart every print job is not an acceptable solution for any application.

In the Windows event viewer, under Custom Views, Administrative Events, the following error is logged at the time of print failure:

"The document Print Document, owned by [user], failed to print on printer [printer name]. Try to print the document again, or restart the print spooler.
Data type: XPS2GDI. Size of the spool file in bytes: 182104. Number of bytes printed: 0. Total number of pages in the document: 1. Number of pages printed: 0. Client computer: [\COMPUTERNAME]. Win32 error code returned by the print processor: 3012. No printers were found."

I have duplicated this bug using the [Windows Universal printing example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/printing/) from Microsoft

I have duplicated the issue on multiple PCs, running Windows 10 21H1, 21H2, and Windows 11.  I believe the issue to be related to some recent security fix deployed by Microsoft but I cannot identify which one is the cause.  The problem did not exist until recently.

Are other people seeing this?  Does anyone know which KB patch is the culprit?  Is there any fix of which anyone is aware?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix.  The fix takes care of both Bluetooth and serial printing issue in Windows with the symptoms as described above.  In an elevated command prompt:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Printers" /v {CA791BB3-9742-4A0F-87B8-B3C4B1065856} /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

After issuing this command, reboot the PC or restart the print spooler service.  The fix works for both Windows 10 and 11.

I’m hopeful that Microsoft is going to patch the issue in the near future.